# How do SKActions change node properties without calling its setter in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit, implementation, skaction

In the documentation for SpriteKit, I found this:

> Generally, actions do not call public methods on nodes. For example, if you want to subclass SKNode to respond to a move(to:duration:) action, you might consider overriding its position property to add a didSet observer.

```swift
class MovingNode: SKSpriteNode {
    override var position: CGPoint {
        didSet {
            // code to react to position change
        }
    }
}
```

> However, because a move action that's running on an instance of MovingNode (defined in the code listing above) doesn't set its position, the observer isn't invoked and thus, your code is never executed.

I find this to be very strange because if actions don't use `someNode.position = newPosition`, then how does the position of the node change? Isn't it impossible to change the value of a property without calling its setter?

However, if you print the value of `someNode.position` every frame, the new position is reflected. So, evidently, something is calling its setter. If it's not the `SKAction` then what is? And whatever is, how is it bypassing the property observer?

Does anyone know what behind the scenes work `SKAction` does to change the value of node properties without calling the setter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this behavior doing something like this:

```swift
class Node { // aka SKNode
    private var _position = 0
    public var position: Int {
        get {
            return _position
        }
        set {
            _position = newValue
        }
    }
    
    public func runAction(_ value: Int) {
        _position = value
    }
}

class ObservedNode: Node { // aka MovingNode
    override var position: Int {
        didSet {
            print(position)
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you do this

```swift
let node = ObservedNode()
node.runAction(10)
print(node.position)
```

You can see the position changed, but you skip the `didSet` observer

Remember `run` runs directly inside the `SKNode` with access to private values.